# hide all windows for a process from command line

Tags: osx-lion

Can I identify all windows associated with a given OSX (Lion) process and hide them?

Ideally, I would set some kind of flag on the process itself to automatically hide any windows it opens.

Is it possible, for example, to instantiate a "null" window manager, which looks like a normal window manager but doesn't actually open any windows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Individual windows can't usually even be hidden in OS X. You can do it with AppleScript though: `osascript -e 'tell app "TextEdit" to set visible of windows to false'`.

Applications can be hidden like `tell app "System Events" to set visible of process "TextEdit" to false`.